# Meteor: Using <script> makes jquery script work properly but using {{functionName}} does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am using a third party package.  When I use a  code the code functions as it should.

```
<template name ="gamePage">

        <h2>Counting down 15 minutes (900 seconds)</h2>
        <div id="CountDownTimer" data-timer="900" style="width: 1000px; height: 250px;"></div>

    <script>

        $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show: false }, Hours: { show: false }}});

    </script>

</template>
```

However, when I try to remove the  and instead have the javascript function be in the page it does not work.

```
Template.gamePage.test123 = function() {
    $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show: false }, Hours: { show: false }}});

};

<template name ="gamePage">

        <h2>Counting down 15 minutes (900 seconds)</h2>
        <div id="CountDownTimer" data-timer="900" style="width: 1000px; height: 250px;"></div>

        {{test123}}

</template>
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: In your script declarations (`<head>...</head>`), are you loading jQuery or Meteor first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `{{test123}}` from your template and use the [rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) callback:

```
Template.gamePage.rendered = function() {
  $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles(
    {time: {Days: {show: false}, Hours: {show: false}}}
  );
};
```

`rendered` is the proper place to do things like jQuery plugin initialization and anything else that requires DOM elements to first be on the page.

Comment: This logically makes sense to me, but unfortunately still does not work.  If I call $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles(
    {time: {Days: {show: false}, Hours: {show: false}}}
  );  from the console it works.  I tried wrapping it in rendered = function() {Meteor.startup( and also does not work

Comment: That's interesting. Does it give you any errors in the console? What version of meteor are you using?

Comment: Meteor 0.9.3.1, no errors in the console.  The package TimeCircles is my first package that I have created.  I am wondering if I did all the necessary requirements right, as it may be something with the load order.   I am adding the package.js file code.  I am stumped, but truly appreciate your help.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure. The path looks a little weird for the `api.addFiles` - that's relative to the root of the package or the project? I could probably diagnose this in a couple of minutes if I could see the source. Any chance you could create a repo with the bare minimum code do demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I believe since I had a {{#if}} in there to manage when the code was displayed was the problem.  Once I put the code in a new template, such as {{#if xyz}} {{> timeCircle}} the timeCircle.rendered = function worked.   I appreciate your help